# $\prod_{a\in A}D_a=\{f:A\to \prod_{a\in A}D_a:f(a)\in D_a\}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, functions

According to my book the Cartesian product of an indexed family $\{D_a\}_{a\in A}$ is the same as the set of functions from the indexing set A such that $(\forall a\in A) (f(a)\in D_a)$.

$$\prod_{a\in A}D_a=\{f: Func(f) \land Dom(f)=A\land f(a)\in D_a\}$$

How can I get some insight into that?

p.s. The book is Kelley's *General Topology*. Chapter 2. After theorem 3, and before theorem 4. This statement came with no further explanation. It is assumed trivial, but I don't see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that Kelley is *defining* the Cartesian product $\prod_{a \in A} D_a$ to be the family you name.

But to gain some insight as to how this works, I am sure you are familiar with "finite Cartesian products" like $A \times B$, which is the set of all ordered pairs $( a , b )$ where $a \in A$ and $b \in B$.  You can additionally think of an ordered pair as a function $p$ with domain $\{ 0 , 1 \}$ such that $p (0)$ is the first coordinate of the pair, and $p(1)$ is the second coordinate.  So, in a certain sense we can consider $A \times B$ to be the family of all functions $p : \{ 0 , 1 \} \to A \cup B$ such that $p ( 0 ) \in A$ and $p ( 1 ) \in B$.

The extrapolation of this idea to the infinite is the genesis of the modern notion of a Cartesian product.

Answer (score 0):

Try a simple example: the set $X = \{5,6,7\}$. The Cartesian product with index set $I = \{1,2,3\}$ is $\prod_{n=1}^3 X = \{ (x,y,z) : x,y,z \in X \}$.

A function from $I$ to $X$ maps every $i$ to an $x$ in $X$. It is the same as a $3$-tuple. Hence the set of all functions from $I \to X$ is $\{ (x,y,z) : x,y,z \in X \}$.

Similarly for infinite sets.